# What are the first steps in order to start with Django/Python 2.7?

Tags: python, django, webserver

I have installed Python 2.7 for Windows, and downloaded Django-1.2.3. Now, I want to build my first website with them. How can I get to the first hello world page, in a browser? Can I use Apache/XAMPP to go to http://localhost ? What are the base principles to get a website working?
Thank you

Comment: Why didn't you read the tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read the excellent and thorough [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). Django comes with a built-in simple web-server that you can run your websites on. It's just a Python script you run, and then you go to a port on `localhost` (by default port 8000). It's really quite simple and well-explained in the tutorial.

Specifically, look at the section named "The development server" in the page I linked to.

Personally I found this basic web-server to be very useful for all stages of website development.

Comment: It's extremely handy.. spits out all the Http requests, can print out emails too instead of actually sending them... does lots of cool stuff, except if you *do* try to send real emails with it, there seems to be a bug that screws up line breaks that isn't actually present on apache.

Answer (score 0):

```
# django-admin.py startproject myone
# cd myone
# python manage.py runserver
```